# I am trying to have event trigger on spacebar for a keydown eventListener that will display random word in array. If conditional statement not working

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <script src="script.js"></script>
      <title>Type Game</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <header>
        <h1>Type A Word Challenge!</h1>
      </header>
      <main>
        <div id="wordDisplay"></div>
        <br>
        <label>Type Word Here</label>
        <input type="text" id="typedWord">
        <h3>Press Spacebar to Begin
      </main>
    </body>
  </html>



    window.addEventListener('keydown', randomD)
 
 
    function randomD(event) {
    const wordList = ['Carvedilol', 'Histrelin', 'Kadcyla', 'Mavyret', 'Paracetamol',     
    'Raloxifene', 'Saxagliptin'];
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length);
    const ranWord = wordList[random];
    const display = document.querySelector("#wordDisplay");
    if (keyCode === 32) {display.innerHTML = ranWord}
    }
```

The display.innerHTML is not working nothing happens when I press spacebar. not sure why if I take it out of the if statement it works but it works for every key on the keyboard not just spacebar like I intended. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Your html is invalid, you need `</h3>` closing tag
2. You are getting errors in the console, but you ignore them. `keyCode` is `undefined`, because you wanted to use `event.keyCode`

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', randomD)

function randomD(event) {
  const wordList = ['Carvedilol', 'Histrelin', 'Kadcyla', 'Mavyret', 'Paracetamol',
    'Raloxifene', 'Saxagliptin'
  ];
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length);
  const ranWord = wordList[random];
  const display = document.querySelector("#wordDisplay");
  if (event.keyCode === 32) {
    display.innerHTML = ranWord
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Type A Word Challenge!</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <div id="wordDisplay"></div>
  <br>
  <label>Type Word Here</label>
  <input type="text" id="typedWord">
  <h3>Press Spacebar to Begin</h3>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you that was the problem I really appreciate it.